# QMouseEvent behaving differently than normal mouse clicks?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I'm currently working on addressing a couple bugs with a touchscreen driver I wrote a couple years ago to support a touchscreen in this application that was running on an OS that didn't have native touchscreen support. My driver simply reads events directly from the device in `/dev/input` and generates QMouseEvents to simulate the touchscreen functionality. If it matters, the original OS was Scientific Linux 6.4, and we're currently running this on RedHat 8.4.

We have since moved to a newer operating system that DOES support touchscreens, but we don't want to rewrite our application to use the native touch driver unless we have to because it's a lot of effort for little gain. So I simply disabled the native touch driver so it doesn't generate extra touch events on top of what my driver generates. However, there's one particular behavior bothering me.

There is a slider in our application that has +/- buttons on the top/bottom that are used to increment it by single ticks. When you click these with the mouse, it just goes up or down by 1 tick. However, if you tap it with the touchscreen, it increments, then rapidly slides up or down to the other end as if you held down a mouse press on the button.

I've verified with log files that both the `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` and `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` events are being generated and targeting the same widget in the same location.

Does QT treat QMouseEvent differently than native system mouse events? Or is there some other explanation for this behavior? Here is an example of how I'm generating and dispatching the events:

```
void InputHandler::touchPress(TouchPoint * tp, QWidget * widget) {
    QPoint screenPos(tp->cx(), tp->cy());
    QWidget * target = widget;
    if(target == NULL) target = QApplication::widgetAt(screenPos);

    if(target != NULL) {
        QPoint local = target->mapFromGlobal(screenPos);
        QMouseEvent * press = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, local, screenPos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
        QApplication::postEvent(target, press);

        DBG(" -- touch press on: " << typeid(*widget).name());

        // Check to see if the target is a QLineEdit or QComboBox, and if so, set focus on it.
        QLineEdit * lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(target);
        QComboBox * comboBox = dynamic_cast<QComboBox*>(target);
        if(lineEdit) lineEdit->setFocus(Qt::MouseFocusReason);
        if(comboBox) comboBox->setFocus(Qt::MouseFocusReason);
    }
}
```

And then the touchRelease method is just the same thing, but without the focus lines and using ``QEvent::MouseButtonRelease`instead of`QEvent::MouseButtonPress```. The way I identify the target widget from the function header is a helper function that does dynamic casts the widget at the click location to various widgets involved in the touch functionality and if the casted object isn't null, I know what widget it is and which touch function to call.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Ok, so the issue was solved by modifying the method to use `QApplication::sendEvent()` instead of `QApplication::postEvent()`. But now there's an issue where although my image manipulation methods work, when I tap buttons, the application freezes or crashes with a segmentation fault and GDB shows the following errors:

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with an active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
```

Comment: Try `QApplication::sendEvent` instead of `QApplication::postEvent`

Comment: @Genjutsu That did it! What's the difference, exactly?

Comment: @Genjutsu It did break some other functionality, though. Tapping buttons no longer works. Just the image manipulation functions I implemented.

Comment: When you call `sendEvent` receiver gets notified instantly. `postEvent` stores events in a queue and notifies receiver once you are back in event loop. I guess that if you are emulating mouse clicks, you want the receiver to act instantaneous. Sorry for breaking your code :)

Comment: @Genjutsu Oh no, it's much worse, lol. Tapping buttons now locks up the application. I guess tapping the button caused a fault. The error says "Unhandled signal handler" for our custom button class that's based off QPushButton... apparently it's a custom error string. No info on the actual fault.

Comment: @Genjutsu Ok, so the application is crashing when I press any button with a seg fault saying "QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected" and "QBackingStore::endPaint() called with an active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?"

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Don't use `repaint()`, use `update()` instead. Does that help?

Comment: @hyde Repaint was used specifically for a 2D and 3D rendering area to ensure the image is displayed before it handles the "render done" event in our code. I don't know enough about the rendering portion of the application to say whether this is necessary but it seems it was done intentionally.

Comment: Well, you have recursive repaint. You gotta stop doing that somehow...

Comment: You almost never should use repaint. Exclusion are very special setup involving QGraphicsScene with embedded object that use non-native rendering (e.g. OSG?) Even in that you usually shouldn't. That's Qt v.3 leftovers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `paintEvent` does something else besides paint. Such as call this `touchPress`, and your `mousePressEvent` does `repaint()`, directly or indirectly.

When you use `postEvent`, this infinitely triggering mouse press loop goes through event loop and you get the repeating click effect. When you use `sendEvent`, there is direct call without going through the event loop, and you get the error you say (and you'd get stack overflow from unbounded recursion, if Qt paint code didn't have that check).

Solution is to make sure your `paintEvent` does not directly trigger any other events. What you should do, hard to say without seeing all the relevant code. If you're lucky, fix is to do "nothing", meaning you now have some extra call/event somewhere, and you just need to find it and remove it.

Comment: touchPress comes from a separate thread which monitors the touchscreen and sends signals to instruct the application what to do. Also, this doesn't seem to be exclusive to any one widget. This happens on any widget I dispatch the event to, not just the rendering areas. Even just regular buttons.

Comment: Even after changing all instances of repaint() to update(), I get the same error, just less frequently.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau QWidgets are not thread safe. Their methods must only be called from the main thread. So to send event from different thread, you _must_ use `postEvent`. Or signal /`invokeMethod` with queued connection type (or automatic).

Comment: Well postEvent was the whole reason the issue with the slider was occurring in the first place, so how can I resolve the issue with the slider without causing this segfault issue?

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Well, figure out why *"if you tap it with the touchscreen, it increments, then rapidly slides up or down to the other end as if you held down a mouse press on the button"* happens. Add logs. It sounds like your mouse press or paint handling somehow triggers touch handling which then sends an event again. Try adding `qDebug` logging to understand what is happening.

Comment: I HAVE logged information, which was provided above. Only one mouse press is dispatched. I use ```xinput``` to disable the touchscreen device when the application is launched so the native touch driver doesn't cause double presses. All I've been able to confirm is that there's only one press and release event generated by my driver, but for some reason, using postEvent causes the strange rapid slide behavior, and sendEvent causes a segfault.

Comment: Using event filter mechnaism to track what events the slider receives is one way to debug. I mean, just log and pass on every event, as a first step.

Comment: I did this, and it shows the same. Only one press and one release event. My only other idea was to revert to postEvent() and see if there's a way to detect if the user tapped the +/- buttons at either end of the slider, instead of the slider itself, and if so, immediately generate a mouse release event with sendEvent because it seems that the delay caused by postEvent is just long enough for it to treat it as holding the button down. But I don't know how to tell if the user tapped the scroll buttons as opposed to the slider button.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Did you measure time between press and release events? Anyway, that suggests a few things: either something is blocking the GUI thread event loop (so the "end-of-touch" event stays in event queue), the touch driver thread is somehow delayed in sending the event, or the scroll bar +/- buttons simply have too short delay before it starts scrolling and too fast scrolling speed. Logging millisecond timestamps might help here. Where is the release event  wing held up?

Comment: It looks like it took 90 ms for the release event to be dispatched after the touch press event. Not sure what is holding up the event, as this is a large scale, complicated application with many threads. So postEvent causes a delay, and sendEvent crashes everything... where do I go from there? A coworker suggested generating a release event with sendEvent immediately after the press event is received, but I would have to be able to know whether the user touched the +/- buttons (the scroll buttons) specifically to do that. Is there any way to detect that?

Comment: Another solution could possibly be... is there a way to disable the hold-click scrolling so it can only do one tick at a time?